# Using Process.Start to capture console output

Tags: c#, multithreading

unfortunately i'm new in C# and this should be a stupid question but i need it, hope someone should help..

Based on this article: http://csharptest.net/532/using-processstart-to-capture-console-output/

i need to use the first code example but applying the second one like described by the Author. He talk about substitute the second code in the first at one point, but i really don't understand how many code to delete and/or substitute..

If it's possible i like to have a working example of that...

Thanks in advance for the help :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given the description:

> you would remove the event subscription and the call to `process.BeginOutputReadLine()`

he is talking about those two lines:

```
process.OutputDataReceived += (o, e) => { if (e.Data == null) mreOut.Set(); else output(e.Data); };
process.BeginOutputReadLine();
```

Note that the code you substitute to this should be just:

```
new ReadOutput(process.StandardInput, mreOut);
```

`ReadOutput` class would be outside the `Run` method (since in C#, methods cannot contain classes).

Comment: Thanks MainMa, thanks a lot. Do you think this is the best way to read a console output? I found few apps that doesn't flush output until the process is done, the way described above should read 'real-time' any application output?